# Issues with JavaScript functions addElement() and insertAt()

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

After doing some heavy reading in David Flanagan's book "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" (O'Reilly), I saw the functions addElement() and insertAt() as a way to create and precisely place new DOM elements.

As a way to test them out, I decided to draw up a script to calculate a Table of Proportional Logarithms. The problem I have is that when I try to run the script from a minimal HTML shell that calls the script, I get next to nothing. The table (24 x 60) doesn't really appear or populate. Here's my script:

```
// Initialize variables to be used in control structures
var hr;
var min;
var x;
var y;
var b;

// Create multidimensional arrays for logarithms and their bases
var logBases = new Array(24);
for (hr = 0; hr < logBases.length; hr += 1) {
    logBases[hr] = new Array(60);
}

var logarithms = new Array(24);
for (hr = 0; hr < logarithms.length; hr += 1) {
    logarithms[hr] = new Array(60);
}

//Initialize logarithm bases to starting point of table
logBases[0][0] = 1440;

for (x = 0; x < 24; x += 1) { //Rows
    for (y = 0; y < 60; y += 1) { //Columns
        if (x === 0 && y === 0) { // If very first iteration
            continue; // Then continue to next iteration
        } else if (x > 0 && y === 0) { // Otherwise, if starting new column,
            b = logBases[x - 1][59]; // Reference last log base of previous column
        } else { // If neither case is true,
            b = logBases[x][y - 1]; // Reference previous log base in current column
        }
        logBases[x][y] = b * ((x * y) / (x * (y - 1)));
        logarithms[x][y] = Math.log(logBases[x][y]);
    }
}

//Grab main table element with "tpl" id
var tpl = document.getElementById("tpl");

////////////////////////////
// Build hour row headers //
////////////////////////////
var tplNumHeads = addElement('tr', 'tplNumheads'); // Create numeric header row
tpl.appendChild(tplNumHeads); // Append header row as last child of table

for (hr = 0; hr < 24; hr += 1) { // Each iteration creates one row.
    var idVal = 'tplHr' + hr;
    var hourHead = addElement('th', idVal, hr);
    insertAt(tplNumHeads, hourHead);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Create table cells and populate with appropriate logarithms. //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
for (min = 0; min < 60; min += 1) {
    // ---Create new row object ---
    var rowID = 'tplMin' + min;
    var row = addElement('tr', rowID);

    // ---Create and insert <th> element---
    var headID = 'tplMinHead' + min;
    var rowHead = addElement('th', headID, min);
    insertAt(row, rowHead);

    // ---Build data cells---
    for (hr = 0; hr < 24; hr += 1) {
        var cellID = 'tpl' + hr + '_' + min;
        var cellHeader = 'tplHr' + hr;
        var cellContent = logarithms[hr][min].toFixed(4); // Logarithms to four decimal places.
        var cell = addElement('td', cellID, cellContent, 'headers', cellHeader);
        insertAt(row, cell);
    }
insertAt(tpl, row);
}
```

Comment: The mentioned methods are not native, there should be some error messages waiting for you in the console.

Comment: Does your [debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) tell you anything?

Comment: Did you wrote the insertAt somewhere else?

Comment: Look into the console and read the errors. If that shell doesn’t have a console, use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). It doesn’t look like you actually defined the two functions.

Comment: I'm using Brackets to write the code, so in the JSLint window, it's referring to the function names as if they were uninitialized variables. I'm wondering if these functions are deprecated or just plain don't exist...

Comment: The message it gives me is, "addElement was used before it was defined". Same for insertAt.

Comment: That’s because, as Teemu already told you, these functions aren’t native, i.e. they aren’t built-in. The book you’re reading defined them somewhere, but you need to actually define these functions before you can use them.

Comment: never heard of these functions before

Comment: Do any of you have information on if there are any native functions that do the same thing, and what they are, including syntax?